# How to change background color of floating action menu

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using this library for floating action button

> https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

If anyone is aware about it, we know that we can change the background color of floating action menu with this line in xml :

**fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/floating_action_menu"**

Is there a way to do so programmatically??

floatingmenu.setBackgroundColor(color)
doesnt work......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got one solution

Add this method in FloatingActionsMenu class :

```
public void setNormalColor(int color) {
        mAddButtonColorNormal = color;
        removeView(mAddButton);
        createAddButton(myContext);
    }
```

It's works for me

Comment: Why remove and create a new AddFloatingActionButton (with `createAddButton`) instead of just change color of already existing one as I explain in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [FloatingActionsMenu](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionsMenu.java) has no getter/setter for this.
To get this feature you can fork the project and add getter for `mAddButton` member of `FloatingActionsMenu` class:

```
AddFloatingActionButton getAddButton(){
    return mAddButton;     
}
```

Then you will be able to call methods of `FloatingActionButton` class :

```
floatingmenu.getAddButton().setColorNormal(...);
```