# How to set icon to getbase FloatingActionsMenu

Tags: android

I'm using the com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu for expandable FAB. But unable to set icon on fab menu. I have tried with set background drawable, but not working.
Thanks

```
         <FrameLayout
              android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/white_overlay">

         <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
             android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
             fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="#C0007D"
             fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="#C0007D"
             fab:fab_addButtonStrokeVisible="true"
             fab:fab_addButtonSize="normal"
             fab:fab_icon="@drawable/main_logo"
             fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
             fab:fab_labelsPosition="left">



        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/locate_store"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#C0007D"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#C0007D"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/locate_store"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_title="Locate Store" />

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my Java Class code,

```
        final FloatingActionsMenu fabMenu = (FloatingActionsMenu)         v.findViewById(R.id.fab_menu);

        fabMenu.setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener(new FloatingActionsMenu.OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuExpanded() {
            frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(240);
            frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    fabMenu.collapse();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuCollapsed() {
            frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
            frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. :(

Comment: Maybe this will help, it is not the answer that I am looking but maybe this is what you are looking for. http://www.rishabhsinghal.in/implement-floating-action-button-similar-to-inbox-by-gmail-or-evernote/

Comment: @Thanos I want to replace the plus sign with a new icon.

Comment: I am working on the same problem, if I get a solution I will posted here also. For the moment nothing yet. :(

Comment: I have found a new library that contains all the modifications and a bit more than what I wanted to include. I think this is also what you are looking for.

https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a possible solution. It is not generic but it fits my needs. If you feel that is not exactly what you need I think is a good point to continue.

So what I did, is to fork the library [futuresimple/android-floating-action-button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button). You need to add the library in the `settings.gradle` file and include the library `include ':library'`. Then in the build.gradle file I remove:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
}
```

I add the library from the project:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Then in the `FloatingActionsMenu` class I replace `private AddFloatingActionButton mAddButton;` with `private FloatingActionButton mAddButton;`. If you check `AddFloatingActionButton` class on line number 59 it throws an exception if you try to `setIcon` on `AddFloatingActionButton` this is the reason. I also added a method to update the icon, colorNormal and colorPressed:

```
public void setMenuButton(int myIcon, int myColorNormal, int myColorPressed) {
        mAddButton.setIcon(myIcon);
        mAddButtonColorNormal = myColorNormal;
        mAddButton.setColorNormalResId(mAddButtonColorNormal);
        mAddButtonColorPressed = myColorPressed;
        mAddButton.setColorPressed(mAddButtonColorPressed);
    }
```

What the method does is simply invokes all the predefined methods on `FloatingActionButton` class where it updates the button.

Next step create a menu button in the layout file (.xml) sample of code taken from the library:

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">
```

Then I choosen to do the rest programmatically in `*.java` file but also parts can be defined in the xml file, such as define the floating buttons. I will not go through the details you can check the library sample directory.

So in my `*.java` file I call the menu button that I have created in the 
`*.xml` file.

```
final FloatingActionsMenu menuMultipleActions = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions);
```

Then you create as many buttons as you want to add, example for one button created programmatically sample:

```
final FloatingActionButton actionA = new FloatingActionButton(getBaseContext());
        actionA.setTitle("Familie");
        actionA.setIcon(R.drawable.world_map);
        actionA.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
        actionA.setColorNormalResId(R.color.red);
        actionA.setColorPressedResId(R.color.black_semi_transparent);
        actionA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainMapView.this, "Action Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ((FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions)).collapse();
                return;
            }
        });
```

This sample of code simply creates the button, add the parameters that you choose to define. Add as many buttons as you need.

Then the next step that you need to do is to set the the menu button. Sample of code:

```
menuMultipleActions.setMenuButton(R.drawable.icon2, R.color.blue, R.color.white_pressed);
```

Then last step is to add the button(s) that you previously created. Sample of code:

```
menuMultipleActions.addButton(actionA);
```

Hope this helps you and solves your problem. Based on my research I have found that someone else has also created something similar with the same Library but I can not find the link now. If you search a bit online you will find it.

For the moment the color on the menu button is not updating correctly but I am working on it, if I find a solution I will update the answer here as well. Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell how to import the library manually. I have already included `:libs:android-floating-action-button-master` in the settings.gradle. And have also added the line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'android-floating-action-button-master')` in the build.gradle file of app module. Still the AS is not able to resolve the class FloatingActionsMenu. Please tell how should I resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather suggest using [this](https://github.com/toanvc/FloatingActionMenu-Animation/) library which is derived from com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu only.

You could change the icon by using following attribute in FloatingActionMenu:

```
fab:fab_menuIcon="@drawable/sort"
```

You can however use all the features of the parent library (com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu).